# Serial comunication with PySerial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

Good evening!

I'm trying to comunicate with an interface unit connected to my COM8 port (via RS232) on Windows andI struggle to understand the functionement of it.

Frist I need to send data in ascii format in order to receive an answer from my device.
When running my code bellow, it looks like the device is receving something (led flashing), followed by the alarm led. Not so surprising to me as I'm still struggling with the format I have to send.

However, the main issue is that I don't receive any feedback from the device as it would be supposed to do (alarm code should be send in return from the device to my pc).

Do you have any tips which would allow me to get a better start with this project?

```
import serial

s = serial.Serial('COM8')

string = 'M0CRLF'
code=([ord(c) for c in string])
s.write(code)

res=s.readline()
print(res)
```

Comment: Although the `s.open()` method is not called, is it a mistake in the question article? Then the `CRLF` in the string would be `\x0d\x0a`, not the character itself. Also, it would be better to add a setting to turn on RTS and DTR.

Comment: ```s.open()``` method is apparently implicitly called, I get the following error if I place it after the port definition line: ```serial.serialutil.SerialException: Port is already open```. But your second advice, replacing the ```CRLF``` in the string, solved completly the issue, I now manage to comunicate back and forth properly with the device, thank a lot!! I don't realy understand why though.. could you please explain? Thank you very much again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CRLF` is a word that comes from a mechanical typewriter and is an abbreviation for `Carriage Return` and `Line Feed`, respectively.

Looking at the ASCII code table etc., it is written as a control code, and the binary value is 0x0D for CR and 0x0A for LF.

Not limited to communication, it indicates the end of a line when displaying text on the screen or inputting from the keyboard, moves to the beginning of the next line, or indicates the completion of command input, and is a delimiter for executing commands.

In the case of text communication, it is often treated as a command input delimiter and execution start.

As for the specifications of communication data, it will be up to the author to indicate such control codes in hexadecimal or abbreviations.

The situation in question is likely to have been abbreviated.